# System.NullReferenceException when published to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, ado.net

Hello I have published my website which was forking ok locally from visual studio to Azure and now everytime I try to access the page I am getting the following exception.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   WebApplication1.Logic.RoleActions.AddUserAndRole() +390
   WebApplication1.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +47
```

Because its pointing to Logic.RoleActions and Global.Application_Start I will post code in those.

RoleActions

```
namespace WebApplication1.Logic
{
internal class RoleActions
{
    internal void AddUserAndRole()
    {
        // Access the application context and create result variables.
        Models.ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        IdentityResult IdRoleResult;
        IdentityResult IdUserResult;

        // Create a RoleStore object by using the ApplicationDbContext object. 
        // The RoleStore is only allowed to contain IdentityRole objects.
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);

        // Create a RoleManager object that is only allowed to contain IdentityRole objects.
        // When creating the RoleManager object, you pass in (as a parameter) a new RoleStore object. 
        var roleMgr = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

        // Then, you create the "canEdit" role if it doesn't already exist.
        if (!roleMgr.RoleExists("canEdit"))
        {
            IdRoleResult = roleMgr.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "canEdit" });
        }

        // Create a UserManager object based on the UserStore object and the ApplicationDbContext  
        // object. Note that you can create new objects and use them as parameters in
        // a single line of code, rather than using multiple lines of code, as you did
        // for the RoleManager object.
        var userMgr = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var appUser = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "canEditUser@wingtiptoys.com",
            Email = "canEditUser@wingtiptoys.com"
        };
        IdUserResult = userMgr.Create(appUser, "Pa$$word1");

        // If the new "canEdit" user was successfully created, 
        // add the "canEdit" user to the "canEdit" role. 
        if (!userMgr.IsInRole(userMgr.FindByEmail("canEditUser@wingtiptoys.com").Id, "canEdit"))
        {
            IdUserResult = userMgr.AddToRole(userMgr.FindByEmail("canEditUser@wingtiptoys.com").Id, "canEdit");
        }

        if (!userMgr.IsInRole(userMgr.FindByEmail("kasi64@seznam.cz").Id, "canEdit"))
        {
            IdUserResult = userMgr.AddToRole(userMgr.FindByEmail("kasi64@seznam.cz").Id, "canEdit");
        }
    }
}
}
```

and Global

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            // Create the custom role and user.
            RoleActions roleActions = new RoleActions();
            roleActions.AddUserAndRole();



        }
    }
}
```

I dont understand why it works fine locally but when published its a problem. Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NullReferenceException` is most likely caused by one of the `userMgr.FindByEmail("xxx")` calls. You do not handle the case where the `userMgr.FindByEmail` method returns null, and you directly access it's `Id` property.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is because there is no user with an email of kasi64@seznam.cz in Azure. Therefore, calling Id on this line will throw a null reference exception.

```
userMgr.FindByEmail("kasi64@seznam.cz").Id
```

Comment: Yes it was exactly that.